# Unable to import linear regression from sklearn module

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, anaconda3

I am trying to import linear regression library from sklearn module using the syntax below with Jupyter notebook:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

But I am getting the error below:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.linalg._matfuncs_sqrtm_triu'
```

I have successfully installed the scikit-learn library several times but issue still persist.

Comment: How are you installing `sklearn/scikit-learn`?

Comment: I tried using both the anaconda3 power shell and system CMD as an administrator running these commands:  pip install scipy and conda install scipy

Comment: Have you searched for the error that you got? What did you find?

Answer (score 0):

Questions:

1. How are you installing scikit-learn, is it via a conda environment/a virtual environment, if so are you activating the environment before executing the said commands?
2. Are you able to import sklearn? is it a sklearn issue or an issue with LinearRegression module, if it is an issue with sklearn, I'd suggest creating a virtual environment/conda environment and try installing from there and try again

P.S.: not able to comment on the question directly, so have written the questions here

Comment: 1. I am installing or installed scikit-learn via conda environment, and yes I activated the environment before executing the commands.

Comment: 2. No, I can't import sklearn as I get the same error/issue as trying to import LinearRegression module

Comment: can you confirm that you installed it in the conda environment you're using?, i.e. use conda list

Comment: From the output of conda list I can see scikit-learn, scipy, sklearn on the list.

Comment: From the output of conda list I can see scikit-learn, scipy, sklearn on the list. With this I can confirm that it is install. But for sklearn I am seeing 0.0 could this be the installed version?

Comment: Can you try removing the 0.0 version and fresh installing a new version ?

Comment: Hello Harsh Sharma, thank you so much for your time. I had I completely uninstalled the Jupyter notebook then install the newest version to fix the problem.